# Add transparent layer on LI

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I need to add transparent layer on LI so when user try to click on checkbox then system treat as like clicked on LI. Here is my code. I have tried to add positions and z index but it not work for me. I need to do it from CSS.

```css
.selectorFilterRow {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #DDD;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.selectorFilterRow [type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<ul class="selector-list">
  <li class="selectorFilterRow">
    <div class="check-pro">
      <input type="checkbox" name="filterCheckbox[]" value="130" class="filterCheckBox">
      <label>One</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="selectorFilterRow">
    <div class="check-pro">
      <input type="checkbox" name="filterCheckbox[]" value="130" class="filterCheckBox">
      <label>Two</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="selectorFilterRow">
    <div class="check-pro">
      <input type="checkbox" name="filterCheckbox[]" value="130" class="filterCheckBox">
      <label>Three</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you cant really do that with purely css as your checkbox is nested inside the li element.. thus 'z-index' did not work. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @zergski I have edited my question add what i am trying.

Comment: yes but why do you need the system to treat is as if you click the 'li' element? are you trying to change something about it like style or behaivour? also 'li' doesn't natively handle input events..

Comment: Which is the transparent layer? I don't see any code for it.

Comment: Yes, I am unable to add transparent layer @Gosi

Comment: I think you are trying to prevent the click action of checkbox, right? or something else?

Comment: Yes, i don't want to click on checkbox @PrakashM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `::after` pseudo element for `.selectorFilterRow`. Here I did that for `.disableCheckbox` class and added this class to last li. [For more about ::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Check below snippet.

FYI: You can disable that check by adding `disabled` attribute to that input

```css
.selectorFilterRow {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #DDD;
  position: relative;
}
.disableCheckbox::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<ul class="selector-list">
  <li class="selectorFilterRow">
    <div class="check-pro">
      <input type="checkbox" name="filterCheckbox[]" value="130" class="filterCheckBox">
      <label>One</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="selectorFilterRow">
    <div class="check-pro">
      <input type="checkbox" name="filterCheckbox[]" value="130" class="filterCheckBox">
      <label>Two</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="selectorFilterRow disableCheckbox">
    <div class="check-pro">
      <input type="checkbox" name="filterCheckbox[]" value="130" class="filterCheckBox">
      <label>You can't click this check box</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```